# How do you set up a click event on a TStringGrid column header (fixed) so visually it looks like you are pressing a button

Tags: lazarus, tstringgrid

I am working with Lazarus v0.9.30.
I have a TForm with a TStringGrid on it.
I have a fixed row in the grid, which is where I have all of my column headers.  Each column is a TGridColumn object and each column title is a TGridColumnTitleObject.  When looking in the object inspector there are no events you can use for TGridColumnTitle.
What I want to do is to be able to click on the column header and visually I want it to look like you are pressing a button.  I want to intercept the click event and then perform an action on it (eg. sort by column text, or perhaps display a help screen).
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your grid set the `Options.goHeaderPushedLook` property to `True`.